# How come useradd isn't working?

Tags: linux, shell-script, rpm

I'm trying to work out the kinks for this RPM I'm trying to create.  Basically, I'm trying to make it so that if `mark` does not exist on the system, I want to create a mark user account.  I've got this in a `%pre` block in my .spec file:

```
id mark &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Adding 'mark' user..."
    useradd -g $GROUP_ID \
        -s /bin/bash -d mark
fi
```

Now, after I build the RPM and run `rpm -ivh iPackage-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm`, I check the output and see "Adding 'mark' user...", but when I run `id mark` on the command line, I get `id: mark: No such user`.  Also, `/etc/passwd` doesn't have a mark account, either.  Any ideas?

Edit:  See my answer.  Turns out, the variables need to be defined.

Comment: There is an error in your script.  Add another space before the closing ']'.   And make sure you run this script as root.

Comment: Another error is that the `useradd` command line is obviously incomplete (unless this is an unusual variant of `useradd`). @Pat: please copy-paste your actual code, and say which distribution you're targetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a moron.  I had a `&2>/dev/null` in my code, so I wasn't seeing my errors.  After fixing that, I found out that a variable I was using wasn't defined for the `-g` switch of `useradd`.

I've edited the question to further demonstrate what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` must be run as `root`.

I don't use an RPM-based Linux, but I guess your pre-install script is running as an under-privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

In my distro `useradd` should be invoked like this:

```
# useradd -ms /bin/bash mark
```

Use `-m` if you want to create the home directory (see `man useradd`).

Also as [Matt H](https://superuser.com/users/24620/matt-h) said, fix that space.